# Get the rows with first phone number

Tags: sql, oracle

I need to display 100 members per page. Because of multiple phone numbers of a member, I have to pick the first phone number for each member.

Here is the query which one gets every phone numbers of a member:

```
    SELECT * FROM 
    (     
          SELECT
          row_number() over(order by(1)) rn, 
          NAME, PHONE    
                FROM MEMBERS t0     
                LEFT OUTER JOIN MEMBER_IDENTITY ON MEMBER_IDENTITY.ID=t0.ID 
                LEFT JOIN MEMBER_PHONE ON MEMBER_PHONE.MEMBER_ID=t0.ID    
                WHERE
          NAME LIKE 'U%' 
          ORDER BY NAME ASC 
    )      
WHERE rn >= 0
AND rn <= 100
```

How can I pick first -or MAX, etc- phone number?

Comment: use row_number() over (partition by Name  order by (1)) ... that way will give you row number for member, where clause should be rn = 1 ... it will give you 1 number per member ... and then just select top 100

Comment: Which Oracle version?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could make a sub query for retrieving the phone numbers together with their row number per member, and then filter out the first of them:

```
SELECT  * 
FROM    (
        SELECT    row_number() OVER (ORDER BY name ASC) rn, 
                  name, 
                  phone
        FROM      members t0 
        LEFT JOIN member_identity 
               ON member_identity.id = t0.id 
        LEFT JOIN (
                  SELECT member_id,
                         phone
                         row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY member_id ORDER BY (1)) ph_rn
                  FROM   member_phone
                  ) member_phone
               ON member_phone.member_id = t0.id
              AND ph_rn = 1
        WHERE     name LIKE 'U%' 
        ORDER BY  name ASC
        )
WHERE   rn BETWEEN 0 AND 100
```

I would:

- use the same order for determining the `rn` value as the result set (`ORDER BY name ASC`), otherwise the order will not be consistent across pages;
- use `BETWEEN` in the outer `WHERE` condition, although the lower bound condition (0) is not necessary for the first page.

Answer (score 1):

When you switch to `MAX` you can apply the `ROW_NUMBER` directly on the name (Windowed Aggregate Functions are calulated *after*  GROUP BY/HAVING):

```
SELECT * FROM 
 (     
      SELECT
         row_number() over (ORDER BY NAME ASC) rn, 
         NAME, MAX(PHONE)    
      FROM MEMBERS t0     
      LEFT OUTER JOIN MEMBER_IDENTITY ON MEMBER_IDENTITY.ID=t0.ID 
      LEFT JOIN MEMBER_PHONE ON MEMBER_PHONE.MEMBER_ID=t0.ID    
      WHERE NAME LIKE 'U%'
      GROUP BY NAME 
 )      
WHERE rn >= 0
AND rn <= 100
```

or move the aggregation into a Derived Table:

```
SELECT * FROM 
 (     
      SELECT
         row_number() over (ORDER BY NAME ASC) rn, 
         NAME, PHONE    
      FROM MEMBERS t0     
      LEFT OUTER JOIN MEMBER_IDENTITY ON MEMBER_IDENTITY.ID=t0.ID 
      LEFT JOIN
       ( SELECT MEMBER_ID, MAX(PHONE) AS PHONE
         FROM MEMBER_PHONE
         GROUP BY NAME
       ) MEMBER_PHONE
      ON MEMBER_PHONE.MEMBER_ID=t0.ID    
      WHERE NAME LIKE 'U%'         
 )      
WHERE rn >= 0
AND rn <= 100
```